Problema para obtener las preview de Contentful
Estoy trabajando en una app de Next 13, usando Contenful como CMS. Tengo todas las api keys configuradas en .env, y quiero hacer que funcione la Live Preview de mis posts
Envolvi mi _app.js con esto
import { ContentfulLivePreviewProvider } from "@contentful/live-preview/react";
   <ContentfulLivePreviewProvider
      enableInspectorMode
      enableLiveUpdates
      locale="en-US"
    >
     ...

Tengo esto en la ruta de mi api, para obtener la preview
import contentfulService from "@/src/services/contentfulService";
import { COOKIE_NAME_PRERENDER_BYPASS } from "next/dist/server/api-utils";

export default async function preview(req, res) {
  const { secret, slug } = req.query;

  if (secret !== process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_SECRET || !slug) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
  }

  
  const content = await contentfulService.getPreviewResortDetailsBySlug(slug);

  // If the slug doesn't exist prevent preview mode from being enabled
  if (!content) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid slug" });
  }

  // Enable Preview Mode by setting the cookies
  res.setDraftMode({ enable: true });

  const headers = res.getHeader("Set-Cookie");

  if (Array.isArray(headers)) {
    res.setHeader(
      "Set-Cookie",
      headers.map((cookie) => {
        if (cookie.includes(COOKIE_NAME_PRERENDER_BYPASS)) {
          return cookie.replace("SameSite=Lax", "SameSite=None; Secure");
        }
        return cookie;
      })
    );
  }

  res.setHeader("Location", slug);
  return res.status(307).end();
}

Reemplazo el contenido de mi aplicacion con el contenido actualizado, usando el hook useContentfulLiveUpdates
import { useContentfulLiveUpdates } from "@contentful/live-preview/react";
const updatedResortDetails = useContentfulLiveUpdates(resortDetails);

Y finalmente tengo mis servicios de Contentful, donde tenia un cliente para traer mi contenido publicado. Cree un nuevo cliente para el contenido preview
const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  environment: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT,
  space: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
});

const previewClient = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_TOKEN,
  space: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  environment: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT,
  host: "preview.contentful.com",
});

Y utilizo previewClient con esta funcion
/**
 * get resort-specific details
 * @param slug
 */
const getPreviewResortDetailsBySlug = async (resortSlug) => {
  const content = await previewClient.getEntries({
    content_type: pageContentTypes.resort,
    "fields.resortSlug": resortSlug,
    "metadata.tags.sys.id[nin]": "mbGolf",
    include: 10,
  });

  if (content && content.items && content.items.length) {
    return {
      id: content.items[0].sys.id,
      ...content.items[0].fields,
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

que es una copia de getResortDetailsBySlug, misma funcion pero usa client en vez de previewClient.
Después de hacer todo esto (y de haber seteado la vista previa en la app de contentful) puedo ver la vista previa de mis contenidos, y puedo ver que si yo agrego un console.log en mi archivo api/preview, todo parece funcionar. Actualizar cualquier campo en contentful actualiza la vista previa, y se ejecuta el codigo de api/preview. Pero lo que me sucede es que el "nuevo" contenido, el cual deberia estar modificado, no lo está. Mi llamada getPreviewResortDetailsBySlug me está devolviendo el objeto en su version Published desde Contentful, aunque yo espero la version modified o draft. Por lo que la vista previa parece funcionar (yo modifico algo y la pagina se recarga) pero no refleja ningun cambio.
Alguien sabe donde está el problema? Muchas gracias

Ni la explotación mineral arrasó tanto como la IA con SO...

Bueno, finalmente lo solucioné. Tenia dos problemas: el primero es que no habia terminado de habilitar la preview en contentful. Para darte cuenta si tenes el mismo problema, cuando estas en el modo live preview el boton publish se encuentra desactivado. Si pasas el mouse por encima podras ir a una url para activar esto. Eso hizo que mi api empiece a recibir el contenido actualizado.

El segundo problema: yo tenia mi pagina con getServerSideProps para exportar props al componente. Si bien la API de la preview obtenia correctamente el contenido, este no era exportado como prop al componente.
Lo que hice fue combinar ambos codigos en el getServerSideProps. Primero modifiqué la ruta de la preview en Contentful para que en lugar de redirigir a la API preview me redirija a la URL del resort, pero agregando el parametro preview.
Ahora en getServerSideProps verifico si el parametro preview existe y es valido, devuelvo el contenido de preview, sino devuelvo el publicado.

Si ya está solucionado deberías poner la respuesta  en la sección de respuestas.

mira crack maquina maquinola del crackismo te doy unos puntasos q capas t ayuden rey, te dejo master, un saludaso y espero t sirva geniol, vos tenes q cerrar el estadio, mastodonte. Misericordia.
fijate que las API keys que configuraste ahí en .env sean correctas y estén bien configuradas. Cualquier error en estas claves puede causar que la vista previa en vivo no funcione como quisieras vos master.
la vista previa en la API:
fijate tu función preview en la ruta de la API. fijate de que estés manejando bien las solicitudes de vista previa y configurando bien las cookies. Verifica que el secreto de vista previa que estás usando sea el mismo que el que configuraste en Contentful.
Verifica que estás envolviendo correctamente tu aplicación con ContentfulLivePreviewProvider en _app.js. mira bien de que los propósitos enableInspectorMode y enableLiveUpdates estén configurados bien o qsy y que estén activados.
fijate de getPreviewResortDetailsBySlug en tus servicios de Contentful. asegurate de estar usando el cliente de vista previa (previewClient) y que estess haciendo la consulta correctamente para conseguir el contenido de vista previa.
Asegúrate de que estás utilizando correctamente el hook useContentfulLiveUpdates para actualizar el contenido de el coso en tiempo real. Que estés pasando el objeto resortDetails correcto y que estés usando bien las actualizaciones en tu interfaz de usuario.
si no t funciono mis consejos top mundiales qsy, fijate la documentación oficial de Contentful y Next.js o busca en los foros de ayuda de ambas plataformas o preguntar en la comunidad en línea si alguien encontro un problema parecido ni idea. Saludaso jasidjasodjaufhbys
